# C++ OpenGL load image in GL_QUAD, glVertex2f

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

Using `WIN32_FIND_DATA` and `FindFirstFile` I'm searching for files in a directory an with `fileName.find(".jpg") != std::string::npos` I filter the jpg images out.

I'm using OpenGL for creating Boxes with a red color:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   glVertex2f( 0.35f, 0.7f );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   glVertex2f( -0.35f, 0.7f );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   glVertex2f( -0.35f, -0.3f );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   glVertex2f( 0.35f, -0.3f );
```

This is the box in the center with a red color.

My Question is how can I load the Images each in a Cube instead of the Red color (glColor4f)?

I think this is not the best way to make this, but this code is not my own Code, I'm trying to make this better for a friend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about texturing. See [NeHe's tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) on the subject as an example.

However, that tutorial is a bit old (as is your code, since you use glVertex(), so it might not matter to you right now... :).

Anyway, starting from OpenGL 3.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0, you should do it with using GLSL,  fragment shaders and samplers instead. See [another tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/articles/article.asp?article=21) for that. It's actually simpler than learning all the fixed function stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good practice to use WinAPI together with OpenGL applications unless you really have reasons to - and loading textures from the disk is not a good reason.

Think this way: OpenGL is a platform-independent API, why to dimnish this advantage by using non-portable subroutines when portable alternatives exist *and* are more convenient to use in most cases?

---

For the loading textures, I recommend the **[SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)** library. This is likely to be much better a solution than what the NeHe tutorials recommend.

For finding files on the disk, you might want to use **[boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm)** if you want to get rid of the WinAPI dependency. But that's not a priority now.

---

When you have the texture loaded by SOIL (a GLuint value being the texture ID), you can do the following:

- enable 2D texturing (`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`),
- bind the texture as active 2D texture (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);`),
- set the active color to pure white so that the texture image will be full-bright,
- draw the vertices as usual, but for each vertex you'll need to specify a texture coordinate (`glTexCoord2f`) instead of a color. (0,0) is upper left coord of the texture image, (1,1) is the lower right.

Note that the texture image must have **dimensions being powers of two** (like 16x16 or 256x512). If you want to use any texture size, switch to a newer OpenGL version which supports `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`.

Not really a lot of explaining, as far as the basics are concerned. :)

BTW- +1 for what Marcus said in his answer. You're learning an outdated OpenGL version right now; while you can do a lot of fun things with it, you can do more with *at least* OpenGL 2 and shaders... and it's usually easier with shaders too.